# Drupal 7 / Drush command / Get logger

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there any way to get an instance to the logger (I know it's a PSR3 logger) from a drush command on Drupal 7?

Comment: What version of drush are you targeting?

Comment: Drush 8 I believe.